# function works onOpen but not when run by timer

Tags: google-apps-script

When I open my sheet the following function takes up to 30 min to calculate all cells. So I'm trying to have a timer set to run this script every h, so when I open the sheet I don't have to wait 30 min.

```
/**
* @param {A1:A2} countRange Range to be evaluated
* @param {A1} colorRef Cell with background color to be searched for in countRange
* @return {number}
* @customfunction
*/

function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\;/).pop().replace(/\s/g, "");
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\;(.*)\)/).pop().replace(/\s/g, "");
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();

  var count = 0;

  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
}
```

Now, when used by timer I get following error:

> please first select active sheet.
>        at countColoredCells(CountColor:9)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you actually getting anything back from `activeRange.getSheet();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line:

```js
var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
```

To this:

```js
var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
```

I hope this is of any help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange), `getActiveRange()`

> Returns ... null if there is no active range.

With a timer, the sheet is presumably closed. And there is no active range to work with.

You'd be better off specifying the sheet you want it to work on. And this function takes parameters. So, perhaps use that to specify the sheet to use.

Comment: Since I have 12 different sheets and it has to work on all, I didn't do that.
But thanks anyways!